# UI SPY unable to detect the Chrome Address and Search Bar?

Tags: c#, .net, ui-automation, inspect, ui-spy

Currently my chrome Version : 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit). but when i am trying to find the Address and Search bar using the UISpy and Inspect.exe not able to detect the Element. when i install the Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m  then its able to detect the Address and Search bar and i am able to get the Url also.

is there any setting to be changed on the chrome to detect the element.

[image: Chrome 64 bit]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Inspect instead of UISpy because with Inspect I was able to find the address bar. I switched to using watch focus and then clicked in the address bar and Inspect found it. Inspect is part of the Windows Kits and can be installed with the [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk). Also I suggest using [FlaUIInspect](https://github.com/Roemer/FlaUI/wiki/FlaUInspect) since it allows the user to switch between UIA2 and UIA3 for viewing the tree.

Inspect showing the tree hierarchy of Chrome. 
[image: Inspect]

Chrome with the address bar highlighted by Inspect.
[image: Chrome]

Edit:
Just noticed that you said you tried Inspect. Can you check and see if the method I used to find chrome works for you. Also can you try manually expanding elements in the tree to find the address bar at the location I found it. Here is the version of Chrome I am running for reference 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit).

Comment: Max Young : but when i try to detect is not able to find the Address and search bar and through code using UIAutomation iam only getting one elements as Chrome Legacy Window.

Comment: @RaviKanth Can you post a screen shot of inspect?